# Android "Cannot resolve symbol '@id/myLabel"

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am getting an error saying "`Cannot resolve symbol '@id/myLabel`'".
same error is for following elements:

```
"Cannot resolve symbol '@id/numberStudents'"
"Cannot resolve symbol '@id/accept'"
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Sample of my xml is being pasted below.

Thanks,
Abhilash Kadala.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/myLabel"
        android:text="Name of student:"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numberStudents"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/myLabel"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/accept"
        android:text="Accept"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/numberStudents"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/accept"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/accept"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to clean up your project.

Comment: Clean or Rebuild will do.

Comment: change `android:layout_below="@id/myLabel"`  to `android:layout_below="@+id/myLabel"` and same to all other ,it may help

Comment: Use @+id instead of @id. e.g.android:layout_alignTop="@+id/accept". Please vote if acceptable.

Comment: your code works correctly in my IDE. try to restart IDE

Comment: Not its not working in android studio.

Comment: @Shailesh This not needful also running code without `@+id`.

Comment: @user3519356 Go to `File -> Invalidate caches or Restart` click on that and restart studio.

Comment: Hi all, @+id is for declaring and @id for using declared elements.

Comment: Everything is fine in your code..just try as jaydroider said....

Comment: Codes seems f9 if still getting error use LinearLayout.

Answer (score 19):

`Rebuild project` has worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Try invalidate caches and restart , worked for me :)

Answer (score 4):

try to reload all from disk [Ctrl + Alt + Y]

Answer (score 0):

It's because you declaring id like this `@+id/accept` and using another place like this `@id/accept`.

Comment: Try to expand your answer briefly.

Comment: ohk u are declaring @+id/accept and u can try to accessing              <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
       
       <!--heare try to @id/accept replace   @+id/accept--!>
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/accept"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/accept"
    />

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using valid caracters...
If everything seems correct... Just close all project, restart Android Studio and it should work (I sometimes have this when loading too much AS).